# Получить атрибуты товара Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Каждый вариативный товар имеет 2 дополнительных атрибута (таксономии). Это цвет товара и цвет света товара. Как можно получить дополнительные поля товара которые связаны и этими атрибутами.
К примеру это мой товар в которого установлен цвет "черный", а цвет лампы "красный".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Товар "вариативный".

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен, если в кого то возникнет та же проблема все поля для разных вариаций товара можно получить с помощью этого кода:

```
$product2 = new WC_Product_Variable(get_the_ID());

$attr = $product2->get_available_variations();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($attr);
echo '</pre>';
```